# OpenDDS - xorg or compiz runs out of memory on Ubuntu 16.04.1 when running 50+ publisher and subscriber

Tags: data-distribution-service, opendds

I'm exercising with `OpenDDS` to understand its behavior. I have a VMware workstation with Ubuntu 16.04.1 (8GB RAM and 30GB hard disk). I would like to run OpenDDS examples `OpenDDS-3.11/examples/DCPS/IntroductionToOpenDDS` as described in `AAA_README.txt`, but with many instances of `publisher and subscriber`.

So I have created a simple script for `publisher and subscriber` which would start the process every few seconds as below,

## pub.sh

`for value in {1..250} ; do
    ./publisher   -DCPSConfigFile dds_tcp_conf.ini &
    sleep 30
done`

## sub.sh

`for value in {1..150} ; do
    ./subscriber -DCPSConfigFile dds_tcp_conf.ini &
    sleep 30 
done`

Here the `publisher` publishes two topics. I first started the `DCPSInfoRepo` followed by `sub.sh and pub.sh` respectively. But what I observed was that the `xorg` or `compiz` runs out of memory after the 50th instances of either `publisher` or `subscriber` is started.

I even tried with `RTPS` but observed the same.

Can someone help me to understand why it's eating up a lot of memory while running many instances?

Comment: (Though this should be in a comment, I don't have the required 50 reputation.) I created a 8 vCPU VM with Ubuntu 16.04.1, 8 GB RAM, 30 GB HDD, and downloaded and built Open DDS 3.11. I created the scripts you listed, but changed it so there were 250 subscribers, and also changed both sleeps to "sleep 1". I never had any OOM errors. Did you make any other code changes?

Comment: @Blistering Sheep, Thanks for your comment. I have modified the following lines in the `publisher.cpp` `ACE_Time_Value quarterSecond( 0, 8000000 ); for ( int i = 0; i < 25000; ++i ) {`, have increased the quarter second to 8 seconds and iteration from 20 to 25000. The rest reamins same.

Comment: It was running successfully for 10 minutes before I ran into OOM, could you run it a bit longer than that and kindly let me know what you observed. I appreciate your help.